# Gravitational intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity

I calculated the gravitational intensity and potential at a point P due to a horizontal linear mass distribution of length '$L$', mass '$M$' and uniform linear density at a distance '$R$' apart from the nearest end on the axis of the horizontal linear mass distribution.

The expression for potential is $$\frac{GM}{L}\ln\left(1 +\frac{L}{R}\right)$$

and the expression for intensity is $$-\frac{GM}{RL +L^2}$$

But if point $P$ is placed on either end of the linear mass distribution, then $R=0 \;\text{or}\; R=-L$ and **both potential and intensity turn out to be infinity**!!!!!

Can anyone please verify the calculations and confirm the results? If the calculations are right, what is the physical interpretation of such a result stated in the previous sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you had a bunch of atoms all equally spaced on the x axis from $x=0 \to x=L$.

The force you feel would be the sum of the forces from each one. And the potential would be the sum of the potentials from each one.

That sum is what you approximate by the integral. (This is where early physics classes and early math classes can be opposite, in an early physics class you might use an integral to approximate a sum whereas in an early math class you might use a sum to approximate an integral.)

But what about that atom at the end? What force and potential do you expect from just that one atom if you are exactly perfectly right on top of it?

And as a related note, if you are using an integral to approximate a sum you shouldn't expect it to be accurate anyway once you consider distances smaller than the spacing you ignored when you pretended the atoms were spread out in a smear instead of being here and there.